# Above the fold: Replace static image with revslider after visible content is loaded

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I use [revslider](https://revolution.themepunch.com/) to display a carousel on my webpage above the fold. Now Google PageSpeed tells me to avoid javascript loading for website parts which are shown above the fold. 
Now my idea would be to show a static image instead of the revslider above the fold and then... when the revslider completed loading replace dynamically the image with the revslider. Is that possible? Have you example code of how to accomplish this?

Theoretically this should be possible at least when I look at this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485273/jquery-select-images-above-the-fold):

Comment: Show me what you have done so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112649/lazy-loading-javascript